# How to contain sections of HTML and other controls within a server control?

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I am trying to achieve something like this in a server control.

```
<MyNewControl runat="server">
    <FirstTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="Red">Hello</asp:Label>
    </FirstTemplate>
    <SecondTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="Blue">Hello</asp:Label>
    </SecondTemplate>
</MyNewControl>
```

I'm hoping to know how to implement that MyNewControl server control to accept those template containers.
I'd like them to allow more complex content than just containing a label.
The goal is to be able to choose which template I want the control to render out.

I've looked around and I couldn't find something that tells me what part of ASP.NET that supports what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you want to use templates (that are bound to a data source), or just embed other controls in yours through markup? In case you need the second thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527573 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to choose which piece of content to render, you could use the built-in ASP.NET MultiView control instead of writing your own.

e.g. ASPX Markup:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="multiExample" runat="server">
  <asp:View ID="viewOne" runat="server">
    <h1>This is my first view</h1>
  </asp:View>
  <asp:View ID="viewTwo" runat="server">
    <h1>This is my second view</h1>
  </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

C# Code-behind code for switching between "templates":

```
  if (condition1)
  {
    multiExample.SetActiveView(viewOne);
  }
  else
  {
    multiExample.SetActiveView(viewTwo);
  }
```

If you'd like to learn how to create a templated user control from scratch, there's an MSDN tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm glad you put it that way...  I'm basically looking to make a custom control that is similar to `MultiView` -- how do I implement my own inner tags (such as `View` in your example).

Comment: The "inner tags" you refer to are "templates".  The link at the end of my answer shows how to create a templated user control (i.e. a user control that you can use the "inner tags" with)

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking to make a server control =)

Comment: @BeemerGuy.net In which case, maybe this will help; "Templated Server Control example": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178657(v=vs.100).aspx